# How to run the code generated by Altova Mapforce in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, map-force

I am using MapForce for the first time. I was able to successfully create an XML mapping. However, I am not sure how to run the generated code in Visual Studio, so that I can use it and see the output. I generated the code for the mapping in C# and did try to run the "Mapping" Project in VS.

Unfortunately, I am not able to due to few errors. There isn't a good documentation on the folders that are created in the project. If I can get a documentation link that I can refer to or if somebody can define why those folders are there and how can I use them/ how I should be running those projects.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated code to `C:\MyFolder\`, then you need to open in Visual Studio the solution `C:\MyFolder\Mapping\Mapping.sln`. Note that the "Mapping" is the default name, if you configured it to be something else from MapForce settings, then it may be different.

Solutions in other generated folders are supporting libraries, and you should never edit them (or at least do so at your own risk). The only file you can (but you don't normally need to) modify is called `MappingConsole.cs`. For example, you may want to change the paths of the mapping input/output files. In any case, after you build and run the solution, a Mapping.exe application is created in the Bin\Debug folder.

It would have been helpful if you indicated which errors you get. Perhaps the paths to the mapping input files cannot be resolved relative to the `Mapping.exe` application?